# send text and image with telegram bot

Tags: python-telegram-bot

I need to send both txt and image to a single message, I see some channel that is doing like this

https://ibb.co/S6XQqnt

I know there is a sendMessage and sendPhoto methods but I need only one message to send

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sendPhoto(caption='caption')